# Modifying PDF and reuse embedded font

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, embedded-fonts, fpdi

I want to modify a PDF document with PHP. I found the libs [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) and [FPDI](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/) which allows to create and modify PDF files. Here is my very simple code:

```
<?php
require_once('include/fpdf.php');
require_once('include/fpdi.php');

// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new FPDI();
// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
// set the sourcefile
$pdf->setSourceFile('input.pdf');
// import page 1
$page1 = $pdf->importPage(1);
// insert the page
$pdf->useTemplate($page1);

// now write some text above the imported page
$pdf->AddFont('calibri');
$pdf->SetFont('calibri','',11);
$pdf->Write(0, "This is just a simple text");

header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
$pdf->Output();
```

That works very well, but I see that the inserted text adds something like a reference to the system font instead of the already embedded font. How can I simply reuse the embedded font?

If that is not possible with that libs feel free to point me to a third free lib.

---

I know that I can just use characters which are already used, but this is no problem in my special case. I have checked that all possible characters are used in the right case sensitivity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bet your embedded font from the imported PDF page is not called `calibri`. (Lower-case only spelling of fontnames in PDFs is very rare.)

And I also bet, that the PDF will not have `Calibri` embedded as a full set. It's rather likely that it is a subset only. And as a subset, the fontname will be composed of a random 6 letter uppercase prefix + the original font name, like this:

```
 AXBTZV+Calibri
```

You have to find that exact name and try with this. (However, I'm not sure if how your PHP library works, if it can do that at all, and if it would handle the modification of the PDF text writing code in the correct way. Gimme the PDF and I most likely can do it in a Text Editor, though...)

Comment: That is interesting. Now I have to check which the random chars are. +1 for the hint so far.

Comment: You are right the font is called QQASDX+Calibri. I'll check tomorrow how to reuse that one.

Answer (score 0):

Reusing fonts in PDFs is mostly not possible since only the characters that are used in the PDF are stored. So if you never used an uppercase `W` in your PDF template and want to add text with one, then it cannot be displayed.

This does not answer your question but rather tells you not to try it at all.

Comment: I know that, but this is no problem in my spacial case. I just need to add some numbers which are already somewhere in the text.

Comment: As a "not an answer" response, it should have been a comment. If your response had included instructions for how to recycle the characters that exist in that font, of course, that would have been different. FYI: I only agree with you partially, since it is possible to embed the entire font and not just used letters. In the end, you gave advice not a solution which should have been a comment instead of an answer. Good details, but incomplete. IMHO ;)